# How to share "screenshot" a entire scrollview in xcode/swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, share, screenshot

Can someone show me where to add frame size or bounds to capture the entire scrollview it's width is set to any and its height is 2200p. 
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBAction func shareButton(_ sender: Any) {

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view!.frame.size, false, 0.0)
        view!.drawHierarchy(in: view!.frame, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image!, nil, nil, nil)

        let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [image!], applicationActivities: nil)

        let vc = self.view?.window?.rootViewController

        activityVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = vc?.view
        activityVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
        self.present(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

}

}

Thats my code, it does take a screenshot but only whats on screen and the UIActivityController comes. Not to concern about renaming it each after each press or what other apps I can share with.

I've look at other post on here and get crashes or countless errors and they are outdated to begin with.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue you're having is because your setting your graphics context size to be the size of your view, which I'm guessing is your view controllers 'view' property which is the same size as your screen.

I'd start by putting all my scrollview content inside a content view (just a UIView to act as a container), and put that content view inside the scrollview.

Then I'd create a category on UIView to create an image of any UIView:

```
public extension UIView {
    /**
        Captures view and subviews in an image
    */
    func snapshotViewHierarchy() -> UIImage? {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)
        self.drawHierarchy(in: self.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        let copied = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return copied
    }
}
```

and call that function on the content view, so the content view is rendered in the context using it's own bounds instead of the frame of the viewController.view.

```
// get a screenshot of just this view
guard let snapshot = myVc.contentView.snapshotViewHierarchy() else {
    return
}

// save photo
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(snapshot, nil, nil, nil)

// do other stuff... etc...
```

Here's a link to a simple demo project that snapshots a view in a scrollview that is 2200points tall and saves the view as an image to the users photo roll.

[Demo Project Github link - https://github.com/appteur/ios_scrollview_image](https://github.com/appteur/ios_scrollview_image)

Comment: I have my views in order of ViewController > scrollview> view then all of content. If that makes any difference but I’ll play with what posted and see if I can make it work from. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Ok, yeah the view within your scrollview would be your content view then, I called snapshotViewHierarchy on that view and saved to photo album and got the full content view saved with a height of 2200points in my test project. Don't forget to add the Privacy keys in your info.plist for accessing the users photo library.

Comment: Great. I’ll give it go. If you share some pictures that would be very helpful but I’ll update with you I get.

Comment: Added a link to a demo project, I tested it on an iPhone 6+. It should help connect the dots for you. Also, you should update your code formatting in your question, your import, class definition and closing braces are not included in your code block.

Comment: I noticed that I posted question and it set that way I tried editing it again and did it again. Then when I was going to try again I started speaking with you. I will update here shortly